# replaceAll Como fazer repetição

Tags: java, replace

quero fazer um `replaceAll` do 0.0 até o 9999.9999
e queria saber se tem outro jeito além de adicionar 1 por 1?

Estava fazendo assim

```
fim = fim.replaceAll("0.0", "0.0f");
        fim = fim.replaceAll("0.1", "0.1f");
        fim = fim.replaceAll("0.2", "0.2f");
        fim = fim.replaceAll("0.3", "0.3f");
        fim = fim.replaceAll("0.4", "0.4f");
        fim = fim.replaceAll("0.5", "0.5f");
        fim = fim.replaceAll("0.6", "0.6f");
        fim = fim.replaceAll("0.7", "0.7f");
        fim = fim.replaceAll("0.8", "0.8f");
        fim = fim.replaceAll("0.9", "0.9f");
```

Answer (score 5):

Se é para adicionar o `f` no final do numero basta usar expressão regular ([regex](/questions/tagged/regex)) ficando algo como:

```
\d+\.\d+
```

O `\d` procura um dígito, o \d+ procura uma "sequência" de dígitos, o `\.` procura um ponto após o número e o próximo `\d+` o mesmo, em Java ficaria assim:

```
fim = fim.replaceAll("\\d+\\.\\d+", "$0f");
```

Precisa de duas `\\` por causa do escape do próprio Java dentro de strings.

Se for só o número vai funcionar bem, mas se for no meio de um texto isto pode não funcionar, por exemplo se tiver palavras compostas, como:

```
foo0.0bar
```

Que apesar de improvável, não é totalmente impossível, então neste caso use o meta-caractere `\b` no começo e no fim da regex, exemplo:

```
fim.replaceAll("\\b\\d+\\.\\d+\\b", "$0f");
```

O `$0` é quem pega o grupo inteiro em uma regex, veja o exemplo online no [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/@inphinit/replaceAll-regex-java).